# Adding display objects to groups in corona storyboard

Tags: storyboard, coronasdk

I am building a 2d platform game in Corona using storyboard. I have put everything in groups so they remove when i call scene:removeAll() and go to another scene. But I have display objects in a function and a loop randomly generating display object that I cant put in a group and so they wont delete when I change scene. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new global group and add it to the self.view on the createScene() method.

```
local globalGroup

function scene:createScene(event)
    local group = self.view
    globalGroup = display.newGroup()
    group:insert(globalGroup)
end

function yourFunction()
    globalGroup:insert(thinsYouCreateInThisMethod)
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, try to add all the display objects in a group at initial stage (at the time of object declaration).
At first you will declare the object and then only use loops to generate random number of objects.
For example:

```
local group = self.view

local object1 = display.newImageRect(GROUP_NAME, "PATH_TO_IMAGE", width, height)
```

and then use this object in any loop to generate multiple random objects.

If you are using storyboard to change scene, use

```
storyboard.removeScene("CURRENT_SCENE_NAME")
```

or

```
storyboard.purgeAll()
```

then use

```
storyboard.gotoScene("NEXT_SCENE_NAME", "EFFECT_NAME", TIME)
```

It will remove current scene and its objects and move to next scene.

Answer (score 0):

u can also use this

local group = self.view

local object1 = display.newImageRect(GROUP_NAME, "PATH_TO_IMAGE", width, height)
and then use this object in any loop to generate multiple random objects.

If you are using storyboard to change scene, use

storyboard.removeScene("CURRENT_SCENE_NAME")
or

storyboard.purgeAll()
then use

storyboard.gotoScene("NEXT_SCENE_NAME", "EFFECT_NAME", TIME)
It will remove current scene and its objects and move to next scene.